# Including a belongsTo association in sequelize

Tags: javascript, database, associations, sequelize.js, belongs-to

I am following the sequelize example in the docs and I am stuck as to how to include an association to the parent in the child model.

In the [docs on associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html), models and the relationships between models are defined like so:

```js
Product.User = Product.belongsTo(User);
User.Addresses = User.hasMany(Address);

return Product.create({
  title: 'Chair',
  user: {
    first_name: 'Mick',
    last_name: 'Broadstone',
  }
}, {
  include: [{
    association: Product.User,
  }]
});
```

The association is assigned to Product.User, and included in the include array.

In the sequelize [minimum express application](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/articles/express/) the models are defined in separate files and the associations are made by calling the methods on the models. In this case I have Message and User, with a belongsTo relationship between one message and its user.

```js
//message.js

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Message = sequelize.define('Message', {
    content: DataTypes.STRING,
    authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  });

  Message.associate = function (models) {
    models.Message.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'authorId',
      as: 'author',
    });
  };
  return Message;
};

//user.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  User.associate = function (models) {
    models.User.hasMany(models.Message, {foriegnKey: 'authorId'});
  };

  return User;
};
```

I think I need to somehow get the association from the models. I followed the docs to make the associations between the models:

```js
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

But how do I do `Message.User = Message.belongsTo(User)` such that when I create the include array do `include[{association: Message.User}]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Right... I realised since the association was already made all I had to do was include the model:

```js
const createMessage = async (message) => {
  const author = await findUser(message.author);
  if (author) {
    const authorId = author.dataValues.id;
    return db.Message.create({
      content: message.content,
      authorId: authorId,
    });
  } else {
    return db.Message.create({
      author: {
        firstName: message.author,
      },
      content: message.content,
    }, {include:[{model: db.User, as: 'author'}],
    });
  }
};
```